# How to build chained methods like - should_receive(:something).with(:params, values).and_return(:something_else)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I was trying to make my code a bit smaller building a method that can look like the should_receive from RSpec, the case here is that I'm testing a state machine and I have several methods with code like this:

```
context "State is unknown" do
  before do
    @obj = create_obj(:state => 'unknown')
  end
  context "Event add" do
    it 'should transition to adding if not in DB' do
      @obj.add
      @obj.state.should == 'adding'
    end

    it 'should transition to linking if already in DB' do
      create_obj_in_db
      @obj.add
      @obj.state.should == 'linking'
    end
  end
end
```

I want to replace these lines of code to something similar to this:

```
@obj.should_receive(:add).and_transition_to('adding')
@obj.should_receive(:modify).and_transition_to('modifying')
```

How are these methods built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part to chaining is to return `self` from the object, so the next call can still work on the object.

```
class Foo
  def one
    puts "one"
    self
  end

  def two
     puts "two"
     self
  end

  def three
     puts "three"
     self
  end
end

a=Foo.new
a.one.two.three
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
class Obj
  def should_receive(msg)
    self.send(msg.to_sym)
    self
  end
  def and_transition_to(state)
    @state == state
  end
  def add
    @state = 'adding'
  end
end
```

Now you can run:

```
obj = Obj.new
obj.should_receive(:add).and_transition_to('adding')
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not ruby-on-rails, but [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/12/06/a-simple-example-of-a-fluent-interface.aspx) gives an example of a [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

```
public class Pipeline
{
    private Image image;
    public Image CurrentImage
    {
        get { return image; }
        set { image = value; }
    }

    public Pipeline(string inputFilename)
    {
        image = Bitmap.FromFile(inputFilename);
    }

    public Pipeline Rotate(float Degrees)
    {
        RotateFilter filter = new RotateFilter();
        filter.RotateDegrees = Degrees;
        image = filter.ExecuteFilter(image);
        return this;
    }
    :
```